# AQT(Advanced Query Tool) Unable to convert an index (employee_id) to primary key

Tags: database, oracle, performance, database-design, relational-database

Working with optimizing my database and I have a problem when trying to edit a table where the employee id is already assigned as a unique index but not a primary key which is what I want.

I get the error message when trying to convert it into a primary key: ”Error during ExecDirect: S1000(2261)[Oracle][ODBC][ORA]ORA-02261: primary key already exists in the table”

Comment: A table can only have one primary key. you need to remove the existing primary key before setting the employee id as your primary key. Please note that the employee id must be unique and non-nullable to qualify as a primary key.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but there are no existing primary keys, only an index, and trying to remove it yields another error: ”Error during Execute: S1000(2429)[Oracle][ODBC][Ora]ORA-02429: "Index that is applied to enforce primary key cannot be dropped."

Comment: do you have any unique constraints other than what's on the employee ID field?

Comment: Yes, there are other unique constraints, but does that matter?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is a bit complicated but you have to undo the unique index before being able to delete it, and if it's associated/linked with another table's indexes delete them first, and then you can delete it.